# Upgrading from a free to paid app in Google Play

Tags: android

I would like to provide two apps. One is free and the other is paid. The paid version has more features. What I would like to do however is to allow the paid app to upgrade the free app and retain all the settings and cached data on the device. What I don't want is to have two apps on the device (one free and the other paid). For that to happen, to the best of my knowledge, both must be signed with the same keystore. Does the Google Play console allow me to do this or do I have to sign my paid version with a different keystore?

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like in app purchase might be a better route for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Why not just put all of the features in the same app, and unlock the premium ones after they've paid for it?

Comment: @CodyHarness If the user uninstalls the app and then reinstalls it, since Google already knows the user paid for it, does the paid features get automatically re-enabled again?

Comment: Exactly. Move to the in app purchases model to achieve what you want

Comment: `For that to happen, to the best of my knowledge, both must be signed with the same keystore` Your knowledge is not correct. Free and paid are two different apps and should have different package name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, the best way to go is use In-App Purchases.

To add an application to the play store you need to indicate if the app is free or paid and you cannot change that. Also the app needs to have a unique package id, so just sign with the same certificate will not replace another application because the package ids are different.

Comment: Is the package ID some combination of the package name plus some signed key?

Comment: No. 

"All Android apps have a package name. The package name uniquely identifies the app on the device; it is also unique in the Google Play store. This means that once you have published an app with this package name, you can never change it; doing so would cause your app to be treated as a brand new app, and existing users of your app will not see the newly packaged app as an update."
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Answer (score 0):

The best scenario so far seem to be provide a basic application, with the minimum features, then use the in-App system to enable the rest of your application